# Не могу создать индекс в redis

Tags: python, redis

Создаю индекс по документации https://redis.io/docs/get-started/document-database/

```
index = r.ft("idx:bicycle")
index.create_index(
    schema,
    definition=IndexDefinition(prefix=["bicycle:"], index_type=IndexType.JSON),
)
```

В методе create_index возникает ошибка

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command `FT.CREATE`, with args beginning with: `idx:bicycle`, `ON`, `JSON`, `PREFIX`, `1`, `bicycle:`, `SCORE`, `1.0`, `SCHEMA`, `$.brand`, `AS`, `brand`, `TEXT`, `WEIGHT`, `1.`,
```

В docker запущен redislabs/redisearch, запускал на windows 10 и wsl